# How to fix 'no suitable driver found' error when connecting to a PostgreSQL database with Java and JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to connect to my postgresql database on my localhost with Java and JDBC. But getting error that is no suitable driver found for this. I successfully connected to the database in the IntelliJ IDEA through in the "Database" tab, but I cannot connect in the code.

This is my Main.java:

```
package org.example;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Main {

    public static final String url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:1234/testDatabase";
    public static final String user="postgres";
    public static final String password="1234maev";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I've JDK version 1.8 and downloaded the .jar file with the postgresql JDBC driver version 42.6.0, included it in the libraries and in the modules (screenshots below).
[image: Screenshot from "Modules" tab]
[image: Screenshot from "Libraries" tab]

How can I fix it?

I expected that my java app will connect to the database. I tried to add driver again, but it didn't work. Connection through the "Databases" tab in IntelliJ IDEA with host, port, user and password worked fine.

Comment: Please [reconsider your use of JDBC on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android).

Comment: Are you actually developing for Android?  Or is that a bad tag and you're on your local machine?  A `main` like you have will not work on Android and certainly not to `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a maven project you should add the driver to your pom.xml like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Probably should be helpful if you post your project structure.